# Scan Mac OS SSD from a Windows PC for malware

Tags: macbook-pro, ssd, scanning

I have an issue with a Macbook Pro and was told to scan the SSD for malware. My other computer is a Windows computer. So I connected the SSD of the mac via USB externally to my Windows PC. As (more or less) expected, the Malwarebytes Software which I want to use to scan the Mac SSD, does not recognize the SSD drive.

**My question is:** How can I scan an externally connected Mac SSD from a Windows PC for malware?

Answer (score 1):

Windows can't read either HFS+ or APFS natively, so you would

1. need 3rd party software to enable that basic requirement, then
2. need a Windows malware scanner equipped to look for Mac viruses.

Why don't you just scan it from the Mac?

Comment: The mac is damaged, hence I cannot just scan from the Mac. Do you know windows malware scanner that can scan for Mac viruses?

Comment: No. I don't think one exists. Most Mac malware scanners mainly look for Windows malware, so as not to pass it on to Win users.